# Quicker way to select different combinations of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataset is:

```
dput(new)
structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1982", "1983", "1985", "1989", "1994", 
"1995", "1998"), class = "factor"), scallopid = 11:20, Region = c("GB", 
"GB", "GB", "GB", "GB", "GB", "GB", "GB", "GB", "GB"), Area = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Nantucket Lightship", 
"NE GB", "SW GB"), class = "factor"), Station = c("1982288", 
"1982288", "1982288", "1982288", "1982288", "1982329", "1982329", 
"1982329", "1982329", "1982329"), Depth = c(68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 
94, 94, 94, 94, 94), Lat = c(40.833333, 40.833333, 40.833333, 
40.833333, 40.833333, 41.183333, 41.183333, 41.183333, 41.183333, 
41.183333), ring1 = c(79.31, 57.57, 75.13, 79.14, 71.5, 76.75, 
72.06, 59.98, 86.6, 67.7), ring2 = c(104.03, 100.81, 95.95, 109.95, 
105.65, 104.1, 98.19, 93.93, 105.31, 100.57), ring3 = c(124.58, 
122.71, 108.69, 122.14, 119.28, 128.48, 122.2, 110.86, 127.91, 
110.6), ring4 = c(132.44, 129.75, 116.96, NA, NA, 135.48, 128.28, 
119.62, 141.16, 124.22), ring5 = c(NA, NA, 123.42, NA, NA, 141.22, 
135.16, 129.49, 148.86, 132.73), ring6 = c(NA, NA, 129.24, NA, 
NA, 145.51, 140.31, 138.12, 152.15, 138.12), ring7 = c(NA, NA, 
134.44, NA, NA, 148.62, 145.08, 143.71, NA, 141.71), ring8 = c(NA, 
NA, 138.2, NA, NA, 152.3, 147.98, 145.43, NA, 144.9), ring9 = c(NA, 
NA, 140.81, NA, NA, 155.9, 150.36, NA, NA, 145.96), ring10 = c(NA, 
NA, 143.13, NA, NA, 158.5, NA, NA, NA, NA), ring11 = c(NA, NA, 
144.81, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ring12 = c(NA, NA, 147.39, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ring13 = c(NA, NA, 148.74, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ring14 = c(NA, NA, 149.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), ring15 = c(NA, NA, 150.62, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), .Names = c("Year", "scallopid", "Region", "Area", "Station", 
"Depth", "Lat", "ring1", "ring2", "ring3", "ring4", "ring5", 
"ring6", "ring7", "ring8", "ring9", "ring10", "ring11", "ring12", 
"ring13", "ring14", "ring15"), row.names = 12:21, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to make a new dataset with the first 7 columns and then different combinations of the rest of the columns.

Long hand way:

```
#ring 1 and 2
gb1<-new[,c(1:9)]
colnames(gb1)[8]<-"ring1"
colnames(gb1)[9]<-"ring2"

#ring 2 and 3
gb2<-new[,c(1:7,9,10)]
colnames(gb2)[8]<-"ring1"
colnames(gb2)[9]<-"ring2"

#ring 3 and 4
gb3<-new[,c(1:7,10,11)]
colnames(gb3)[8]<-"ring1"
colnames(gb3)[9]<-"ring2"
```

etc.  I do this for all columns and then rbind them to get them back into one dataframe.

Is there a streamlined way to do this?

The end result that I am looking for is:

```
  Year scallopid Region         Area Station Depth      Lat  ring1  ring2
2  1982         1    MAB VA/NC Border  198297    50 36.68333  78.56  95.45
21 1982         1    MAB VA/NC Border  198297    50 36.68333  95.45 109.49
22 1982         1    MAB VA/NC Border  198297    50 36.68333 109.49 117.20
23 1982         1    MAB VA/NC Border  198297    50 36.68333 117.20 125.86
24 1982         1    MAB VA/NC Border  198297    50 36.68333 125.86 130.75
25 1982         1    MAB VA/NC Border  198297    50 36.68333 130.75 133.32
```

For each scallopid, the initial ring1 value is the original ring1 value.  The ring2 value is the next ring column value in the same row, so for the first record it would be ring .  For the next row for the same scallopid: ring1 would be the value of the ring2 column and ring2 would be the value from the ring3 column and so on.

Comment: Depending on what you're ultimate goals are it might be easier to `tidyr::gather()` all the rings into one column. Then if you `arrange()` the resulting data frame, you can operate on successive `ring` values in a pretty compact way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider doing what you are showing manually in a loop by iterating sequentially through *ring* column names to build a list of dataframes that you can row bind at the end. The `if` logic within function is needed for very last iteration which will have an empty *ring2*.

```
id_cols <- colnames(new[1:7])
ring_cols <- colnames(new)[8:ncol(new)]

dfList <- lapply(seq_along(ring_cols), function(i) {
  if (is.na(ring_cols[i+1])) {
    tmp <- new[,c(id_cols, ring_cols[i])]
    tmp$ring2 <- NA
  } else {
    tmp <- new[,c(id_cols, ring_cols[i:(i+1)])]
  }

  colnames(tmp)[8:9] <- c("ring1", "ring2")
  return(tmp)
})

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending @joran's suggestion, we can label each ring into `ring1` or `ring2` after gathering, which can then be operated on by the new grouping:

```
library(tidyverse)

new.long = new %>% 
  gather(ring, value, ring1:ring15) %>% 
  group_by(ring) %>% 
  mutate(ring_group = ifelse(as.numeric(gsub("ring","", ring)) %% 2 == 1, "ring1", "ring2"))
```

**UPDATE:** Your updated example doesn't use the data you posted, and the data you posted contains only one row for each `scallopid`, so I'm not certain if the code below is on the right track. Let me know.

```
new.long = new %>% 
  select(Year:Lat, paste0("ring", seq(1,15,2)))
  gather(ring, ring1, ring1:ring15) %>% 
  group_by(scallopid, ring) %>% 
  mutate(ring2 = lead(ring1))
```

Comment: That is close, but when I run the code it skips assigning a combination for the original ring 2 as ring 1 and ring 3 as ring 2.  It does that for all combinations.  I kindof need a lag.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've posted the first 30 rows of output. Can you let me know how it should actually look?

Comment: Sorry - I updated my question.  Hopefully that will clarify what I need.